# Escape key is not being detected by my program Delphi

Tags: delphi, keypress

I want my program to detect if ESC key is pressed to do something, but it's not detecting it !
I want to detect the escape key pressing during the whole runtime even if focus is set on another component !
I tried this code

```
if key=#27 then
 begin
  //do something
 end;
```

any suggestions please ?

Comment: You need to be much more specific.  Where is this code in your program?  Some kind of key event I'm sure, but what specifically?  Also key events tend to default to the active control unless you set KeyPreview to true.

Comment: @Glenn1234 I've Set Keypreveiw to true in the OnCreate Event, this code is in onkeypress event of the form1 , I press escape key but nothing happens !

Comment: That's the problem.  OnKeyPress is only for alphabetic characters.  It needs to be in the OnKeyDown or OnKeyUp events.

Comment: Assuming you're wanting to hook the escape key *only in your own program*, set your Form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`.

Comment: Do you want to detect this system wide?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I didn't understand your question !

Comment: Only when your app is active, or escape pressed at any time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which event handler are you using? If it's connected to a control, the event will be fired when a key is pressed and the **control** has focus.

If you want the event to fire when a key is pressed while your **application** has focus, drop a TApplicationEvents component on a form and add an OnMessage event handler something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.message of
    WM_KEYDOWN:
      if Msg.wParam = 27 then
      begin
        // Do something
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: my code is written in onkeypress event of form1 , in runtime nothing happens when I press escape

Comment: I'm getting this error : [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(104): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TForm1.FormKeyDown'

Comment: Why  post a  compiler error without code? What do you expect us to do?

Comment: @Billo.S this is not a simple copy-paste solution. HowTo is right in the answer, just follow it.

Answer (score 4):

To formalize what I wrote above as an answer, borrowing from the Delphi 3 help for OnKeyDown

*The following code aborts a print job if the user presses Esc. Note that you should set KeyPreview to True to ensure that the OnKeyDown event handler of Form1 is called.*

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  begin
    if (Key=VK_ESCAPE) and Printer.Printing then
      begin
        Printer.Abort;
        MessageDlg('Printing aborted', mtInformation, [mbOK],0);
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: it's not working ! I used your very code to press a button on Escape key pressing but it's not working ! when focus is not on the form it doesn't work , it works on when application is activated but if you press anything it doesn't work anymore !

Comment: it's not working during runtime !

Comment: Well, naturally the event only fires when the form is active.

Comment: Okay, so you changed your requirements again, but you haven't really stated them well anyway.  You might try stating them in a much more clearer manner than you have so far.

Comment: So I have to get a timer which set focus to the form to detect escape key press ? @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Not necessarily. But what is your real problem. The comments don't match the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my problem is I want app to close if escape key is pressed during runtime at anytime !

Comment: Then norgepaul's answer does what you need. But all these requirements should be in the question

Comment: @Billo.S: Please stop adding details in comments, and edit your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do. Making us play 20 questions trying to figure it out is not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I couldn't understand it ! can you please make it more simple @DavidHeffernan ?

Comment: @KenWhite I modified the question ! I'm sorry for all the bother I caused but I couldn't clarify my problem at the first time !

Comment: Try harder to understand it.

Comment: @Billo.S: Try editing again. There's still information missing that is available in the comments (your question doesn't even make it clear that you're asking about a VCL forms application and not a console application, for instance). David has asked you to clear up things as well, and those should be made clear in the question. We can't help you if you can't explain what you want help with *clearly*.

Comment: @KenWhite I mentioned component and this declares I'm using VCL not console , but thank you for saying so.